# How do I display my current position using Vue Google Maps

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps-api-3, quasar-framework

> When I run my code, a map shows up with coordinates 0, 0, which is where I initialize it, but the location is not updating to my current location as it should when I set lat equal to position.coords.latitude and lng to position.coords.longitude. Any ideas what could be wrong?

```js
<template>
        <GmapMap
            :center="{lat: center.lat, lng: center.lng}"
            ...
          />
</template>


<script>
export default {
data () {
  return {
    center : { 
      lat : 0, 
      lng : 0 
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  getCurrentPosition() {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(position => {
      console.log('Current', position)
      this.position = position
      this.center = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        }
    })
  },
 mounted () {
    this.getCurrentPosition(
    this.geoId = Geolocation.watchPosition({enableHighAccuracy: true}, (position, err) => {
      this.position = position
    })
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should give more information about the dependencies you're using, and give a proper sample of code (the one you gave us at first will not compile).

---

From what I can see of the code, it might seem like a reactivity problem.

If you want **Vue** to register changes when you're ***updating an object***, be sure to use [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set) to do so.

Instead of

```js
this.center = {
  lat: position.coords.latitude,
  lng: position.coords.longitude
}
```

use:

```js
Vue.set(this, 'center', {
  lat: position.coords.latitude,
  lng: position.coords.longitude
})
```

---

Alternatively, you could use this trick:

```js
this.center = Object.assign({}, this.center, {
  lat: position.coords.latitude,
  lng: position.coords.longitude
})
```

[Vue.js Reactivity in Depth](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects)

Comment: My apologies for the lack of information and incomplete code. I had the complete code at first, but it said I couldn't submit because of the amount of code compared to text.I guess I should've filled the text with dependencies info. Thanks for the response. I'm trying to use Object.assign, and the map still isn't shifting away from the original coordinates towards current position. I know my position is updating because I am console logging when it updates, but the map doesn't shift. Could there be a more specific problem with maps? Or should I be using Object.assign in mounted?

Comment: If you figured it out, please post the answer for others. They might come across the same problem :)